# Circle Navigation Effect with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very new to jQuery and would like to animate a circle button on my web page.

From finding a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLu7v/38/) I adapted it as far as I could with my limited Javascript knowledge. Here is my current **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FcBPh/)**.

**My Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/FcBPh

I was wondering if I could do the following with it:

**1.** Fix the circle element to one position. Currently it expands outwards in equal direction, I'd like to expand but still remain in the same position - so perhaps it opens out to the right?

**2.** Is it possible to stick the 'placehold' graphic outside the circle, so it pokes out a little?

My HTML:

```
<div id="seven" class="circle">
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="position:relative;margin-top:-20px" /></div>
    <div style="float:left;margin-left:100px">click me. texty text, some long text wrapping</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
//setup
$( ".circle" ).each( function() {

    var radius = $( this ).outerWidth() / 2,
        left = $( this ).offset().left,
        top = $( this ).offset().top;

    $( this ).data( { 

        "radius": radius, 
        "left": left, 
        "top": top,
        "clicked": false

    } );

    $( "body" ).data ( { "hovering":false } );

} );

//move and expand
function setLocations( circle, expand, event )  {

    var $this = $( circle ),
        circle = $this.data(),
        hoveredX = circle.left + circle.radius,
        hoveredY = circle.top + circle.radius;

    $( "body" ).data( "hovering", true );

    //expand circle you're over
    $this.animate( { 

        "width": ( 2 * circle.radius ) + expand + "px",
        "height": ( 2 * circle.radius ) + expand + "px",
        "left": circle.left - ( expand / 2 ) + "px",
        "top": circle.top - ( expand / 2 ) + "px",
        "border-top-left-radius": circle.radius + ( expand / 2 ) + "px",
        "border-top-right-radius": circle.radius + ( expand / 2 ) + "px",
        "border-bottom-left-radius": circle.radius + ( expand / 2 ) + "px",
        "border-bottom-right-radius": circle.radius + ( expand / 2 ) + "px"

    }, 75 );

    //images have to be done separately
    $this.children( "img" ).animate( { 

        "border-top-left-radius": circle.radius + ( expand / 2 ) + "px",
        "border-top-right-radius": circle.radius + ( expand / 2 ) + "px",
        "border-bottom-left-radius": circle.radius + ( expand / 2 ) + "px",
        "border-bottom-right-radius": circle.radius + ( expand / 2 ) + "px"

    }, 75 );

    //text in circle
    if( $this.children( "div" ).length ) {

        var h = circle.radius + ( expand / 2 ),
            a = h / Math.sqrt( 2 ),
            size = 2 * a,
            padding = h - a;

        $this.children( "div" ).animate( { 

            "left": padding,
            "top": padding,
            "width": size,
            "height": size

        }, 75 );

    };

    //move other cicles out of the way
    $this.siblings( ".circle" ).each( function() {
        debugger;
        var $this = $( this );
        var circle = $this.data();
        var circleX = circle.left + circle.radius;
        var circleY = circle.top + circle.radius;
        var angle = Math.atan2(hoveredY - circleY, hoveredX - circleX);
        var topMove = ((expand /2 ) * Math.sin(angle));
        var leftMove = ((expand /2 ) * Math.cos(angle));

        $this.animate( { 

            "left": "-=" + leftMove + "px",
            "top":  "-=" + topMove + "px"

        }, 75 );

    });

};

//put everything back the way it was
function resetLocations() {

    $( ".circle" ).each( function() {

        var $this = $( this ),
            circle = $this.data();

         $this.stop().animate( { 

            "width": ( 2 * circle.radius ) + "px",
            "height": ( 2 * circle.radius ) + "px",
            "left": circle.left + "px",
            "top": circle.top + "px",
            "border-top-left-radius": circle.radius + "px",
            "border-top-right-radius": circle.radius + "px",
            "border-bottom-left-radius": circle.radius + "px",
            "border-bottom-right-radius": circle.radius + "px"

        }, 75 );

        $this.children( "img" ).stop().animate( { 

            "border-top-left-radius": circle.radius + "px",
            "border-top-right-radius": circle.radius + "px",
            "border-bottom-left-radius": circle.radius + "px",
            "border-bottom-right-radius": circle.radius + "px"

        }, 75 );

        if( $this.children( "div" ).length ) {

            var h = circle.radius,
                a = h / Math.sqrt( 2 ),
                size = 2 * a,
                padding = h - a;

            $this.children( "div" ).animate( { 
                "left": padding,
                "top": padding,
                "width": size,
                "height": size

            }, 75 );

        };

    } );

    $( "body" ).data( "hovering", false );

};

//is mouse inside circle or in "corner" of div
function inCircle( circle, x, y ) {

    var radius = circle.outerWidth() / 2,
        circleX = circle.offset().left + radius,
        circleY = circle.offset().top + radius,
        xDiff = ( circleX - x ),
        yDiff = ( circleY - y ),
        mouseDistance = Math.sqrt( ( xDiff * xDiff ) + ( yDiff * yDiff ) );

    return ( mouseDistance > radius ? false : true );

};

$( ".circle" ).mouseleave( function( event ) {

    resetLocations();
    $( this ).data( "clicked", false );

});

$( ".circle" ).mousemove( function( event ) {

    if( inCircle( $( this ), event.pageX, event.pageY ) ) {

        if ( !$( "body" ).data( "hovering" ) ) {

            setLocations( this, 40, event );

        };

    } else {

        if ( $( "body" ).data( "hovering" ) ) {

            resetLocations();
            $( this ).data( "clicked", false );

        };

    };

});

$( ".circle" ).click( function( event ) {

    if( $( this ).data( "clicked" ) ) {

        resetLocations();
        $( this ).data( "clicked", false );

    } else {

        if( inCircle( $( this ), event.pageX, event.pageY ) ) {

            $( this ).data( "clicked", true );
            setLocations( this, 200, event );

        } else {

            resetLocations();
            $( this ).data( "clicked", false );

        };

    };

});
```

**CSS**

```
.circle {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

#seven
{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
}

#seven div
{
    /* h=radius, a=h/sqrt(2), height=width=2a, left=top=h-a */
    height: 128px;
    left: 26px; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    width: 128px;

}
```

Many thanks for any pointers with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the circle element to the top left so it expands to the bottom right, comment out these two lines:

```
"left": circle.left - ( expand / 2 ) + "px",
"top": circle.top - ( expand / 2 ) + "px",
```

And to make the contents of the circle stick outside of it, remove `overflow:hidden;` in the CSS for the `.circle` element.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, Simon. I will try this out right now and get back to you.

Comment: I came with the same simple solution, fixing z-index too: http://jsfiddle.net/uLu7v/62/

Comment: Can you show me what line of code I've to make the first set of updates to? I added `overflow: hidden` but it appears to have caused an issue > http://jsfiddle.net/FcBPh/1/

Comment: @michaelmcgurk I think the problem you're having in your fiddle is a few rubbish characters on the sixth line of Javascript...

Comment: Good spot, I just noticed that too. Odd. Do you think it'll be possible to poke the top of the graphic above the circle, without it breaking out of the circle?

Comment: @SimonM Your update to keep the circle fixed is perfect. I just need to fix the way the graphic sticks out. Any ideas? :-)

Comment: Sadly that doesn't fix the graphic poking out issue. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/9y93W/2/ Thanks for your ongoing help with this - really appreciate it.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9y93W/2/)? (I added a square container element and made that `overflow:hidden`)

Comment: @SimonM Still doesn't seem to work for me. It just needs the top part of the graphic to be poking out above the circle. The rest should be within the circle. Sorry, my description could have been better earlier.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Okay, that's probably a lot harder to do, and my laptop battery is showing 'two minutes remaining'... Sorry :(

Comment: Hehe, that's ok. I'll have a think at this end. Thanks for your persistence and patience with this. I may have to position a cut of the image absolutely above it and still use `overflow:hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove this line in css

```
overflow: hidden;
```